# client/server chat in Linux using threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, client, posix

I'm trying to implement client server chat in Linux using threads, but run in to strange behavior.
I'm trying to get message from client into buffer and then send him back the message, but i only get the message and the message is not sent back to client. What could be the reason ??
Code explanation:
I'm opening one FIFO for the server so other clients can connect to it using special message. For this purpose i create a thread that will be doing only this task. 
After the client is connected, i'm talking with the client throughout 2 FIFO's:
one for incoming messages, and one for outgoing.
Now what i try to do is get message from the client that already connected to the server, and then send it back to him, using two threads, each thread for write or read purpose, but i only succeed to get the message from the client, but client couldn't get it back.
What can be the problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

The source attached.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGHT 10240

void server_signal_handler();
void *server_fifo_read_thread(int id);
void *server_fifo_write_thread(int id);
void *server_main_fifo_connection();
char mess_buffer[1000];
int main() {

    char server_fifo_path[] = "/tmp/server-fifo";

    int server_fifo = mkfifo(server_fifo_path, 0666);
    if (server_fifo < 0) {
        printf("Error creating server fifo\n");
        return -1;
    }
    server_fifo = open(server_fifo_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (server_fifo < 0) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }   

    pthread_t server_main_fifo_thread;
    pthread_create(&server_main_fifo_thread, NULL, server_main_fifo_connection, (int*)server_fifo);
    pthread_join(server_main_fifo_thread, NULL);
}


void *server_main_fifo_connection(int server_fifo){
    while (1){          
        char buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGHT];
        while (read(server_fifo, buffer, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGHT) == 0); // Wait for client initial message

        int message_length = *((int*)buffer);
        int client_id = *( (int*)(buffer + sizeof(int)) );
        char* client_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (message_length + 1));
        memcpy(client_name, buffer + 2*sizeof(int), message_length);
        client_name[message_length+1] = '\0'; 
        pthread_t write_thread;
        pthread_create(&write_thread, NULL, server_fifo_write_thread, (int*)client_id);

    }
}

void *server_fifo_write_thread(int id){
    int write_fifo;
    char fifo_write_path[20];
    sprintf(fifo_write_path, "/tmp/fifo-%d-in", id);
    write_fifo = open(fifo_write_path, O_WRONLY);
    if (write_fifo < 0){
        printf("Error opening write FIFO");
        return;
    }
    pthread_t read_thread;
    pthread_create(&read_thread, NULL, server_fifo_read_thread, (int*)id);
    write(write_fifo, "/ack", 5);
    while(1){
        write(write_fifo, mess_buffer, strlen(mess_buffer));
    }

}

void *server_fifo_read_thread(int id){
    int read_fifo;
    char fifo_read_path[20];
    sprintf(fifo_read_path, "/tmp/fifo-%d-out", id);
    read_fifo = open(fifo_read_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (read_fifo < 0){
        printf("Error opening read FIFO");
        return;
    }
    while(1){
        while (read(read_fifo, mess_buffer, strlen(mess_buffer)) == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: somebody ? is the question too long ?

Comment: The length is ok.  There are some conceptual problems and a dozen or so minor coding errors.  It leads to a somewhat lengthy answer and then posters get all excited about getting it to work and pepper respondents with ongoing questions.  So some people stay away from questions like this as they become more work than they bargained for with not much reward.  If I get a chance I'll look at it again later.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would to hear about coding errors and concepts because the threads are new to me and i don`t know exactly how to handle them.